# how to put condition in selected method annotation mapkit?

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have one method that add selected method for any annotation in my map but I don't want this method working for my annotation location (user location annotation) and I don't know how do it?

this is my code that add select method to any annotation and I want that this method don't working for my user location annotation.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSString *action = (__bridge NSString *)context;
    if ([action isEqualToString:ANNOTATION_SELECTED_DESELECTED]) {
        BOOL annotationSelected = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];
        if (annotationSelected) {
            NSLog(@"Annotation was selected, do whatever required");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Annotation was deselected, do what you must");
        }
    }
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

    for (MKAnnotationView *anAnnotationView in views) {
        if (!Change) {
            [anAnnotationView setCanShowCallout:NO]; //this method is for show popover annotation
            [anAnnotationView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(__bridge void *)(ANNOTATION_SELECTED_DESELECTED)];
            NSLog(@"%@",anAnnotationView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using KVO to detect annotation selection?  Why not use the didSelectAnnotationView delegate method instead and you won't need to do all this observe stuff?  In any case, you can check if view.annotation is of type MKUserLocation.

Comment: @Anna my friend I so confused please tell me with code?

Comment: In the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method, it would be something like: `if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) { //handler user-location tap } else { //handle non-user-location tap }`